# Mobile App Recommendation: How to get the rate of a specific user submit for a specific application

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, recommender-system, matrix-factorisation

I have a mobile app recommendation project, so I need data set which has user-app matrix-rate.
Actually, I want to know what rate does a specific user submit for a specific application.
in other words, "user-app matrix-rate" is a 2-D matrix, rows are users, columns are applications and cell(i,j) is rate of user i submit for application j.

In addition, It's good for me to know "user-app matrix-install" where
"user-app matrix-install" is a 2-D matrix, rows are users, columns are applications and cell(i,j) is 1 if user i installed application j, otherwise cell(i,j) is 0

thanks for your help